# Issues building PyQt5 for Python3.4 in Ubuntu 14.04 caused by qprinter.h not found then pyuic5 error

Tags: build, qmake, python-3.4, pyqt5, qprinter

After installing the latest SIP, and the latest Qt5, I tried to build the latest PyQt5 for python 3.4.

I launched pyqt5 configure like this:

```
python3 configure.py --qmake=/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake
```

Then make and sudo make install.
During sudo make install I obtain this error:

```
cd QtWebKitWidgets/ && ( test -e Makefile || /opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake /home/me/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5.3.2/QtWebKitWidgets/QtWebKitWidgets.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/me/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5.3.2/QtWebKitWidgets'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_WEBKITWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I. -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtWebKitWidgets -I/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtWebKit -I/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork -I/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -o sipQtWebKitWidgetsQWebView.o sipQtWebKitWidgetsQWebView.cpp
sip/QtPrintSupport/qprinter.sip:28:22: fatal error: qprinter.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [sipQtWebKitWidgetsQWebView.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/me/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5.3.2/QtWebKitWidgets'
make: *** [sub-QtWebKitWidgets-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
```

I can import QtCore, QtGui, etc. but not modules alphabetically after QtWebKitWidgetsQWebView like QtWidgets...

EDIT:
First patch

```
$ sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
```

Then after make and sudo make install I get this error:

```
install -m 755 -p /home/me/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5.3.2/pyuic5 /usr/bin/
strip /usr/bin/pyuic5
strip:/usr/bin/pyuic5: File format not recognized
make: [install_pyuic5] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Answer (score 0):

`qprinter.h` is in the QtPrintSupport module in Qt 5.3 but that include directory is not in the compiler command. Modifying `configure.py` such that

```
'QtWebKitWidgets':    ModuleMetadata(qmake_QT=['webkitwidgets', 'printsupport']),
```

instead of

```
'QtWebKitWidgets':    ModuleMetadata(qmake_QT=['webkitwidgets']),
```

resolves the build failure.