# PyQt4 make Error sip/QtGui/qprinter.sip:34:22: fatal error: qprinter.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qgis

QGIS requires PyQt4 for Python Support  PyQt4 not available at PyPi with pip/pip3 etc ...

Building PyQt4 from source - got the Zip from SourceForge

Ascertained facts basis - Source - http://blog.qgis.org/2016/02/10/qgis-3-0-plans/

1. QGIS 2.14 Requires PyQt4 for Python Support and will not run Python Plugins with PyQt5
2. QGIS 3.* will NOT Require PyQt4 for Python Support ,will run Python Plugins with PyQt5

While installing PyQt4 at the "make" stage got the below error -

```
    make[1]: Entering directory '/media/dhankar/Dhankar_1/a1_18/a1_______QGIS/QtWebKit'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x04ffff -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_WEBKITWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I/home/dhankar/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -I/home/dhankar/anaconda2/include/qt -I/home/dhankar/anaconda2/include/qt/QtWebKitWidgets -I/home/dhankar/anaconda2/include/qt/QtWebKit -I/home/dhankar/anaconda2/include/qt/QtWidgets -I/home/dhankar/anaconda2/include/qt/QtGui -I/home/dhankar/anaconda2/include/qt/QtNetwork -I/home/dhankar/anaconda2/include/qt/QtCore -I. -I/home/dhankar/anaconda2/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o sipQtWebKitQWebFrame.o sipQtWebKitQWebFrame.cpp
sip/QtGui/qprinter.sip:34:22: fatal error: qprinter.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:3450: recipe for target 'sipQtWebKitQWebFrame.o' failed
make[1]: *** [sipQtWebKitQWebFrame.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/dhankar/Dhankar_1/a1_18/a1_______QGIS/QtWebKit'
Makefile:577: recipe for target 'sub-QtWebKit-make_first-ordered' failed
make: *** [sub-QtWebKit-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

What i presume i need to do to fix this issue -

1. Need to correct "include-paths for the header" file == qprinter.h
2. In other words - need to correct include directives for the header file == qprinter.h

But am not able to trace the Path and also the header file == qprinter.h

Have referred the undermentioned resources no headway yet -

- Transition from Qt4 to Qt5 --- https://wiki.qt.io/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231382/installing-qgis-2-14-9-essen-with-qt-5-6-1-on-rhel7-64-bit
- [Qt Cannot open include file: 'QPrinter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145763/qt-cannot-open-include-file-qprinter)
- [PyQt static build fails at make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700790/pyqt-static-build-fails-at-make)
- [Issues building PyQt5 for Python3.4 in Ubuntu 14.04 caused by qprinter.h not found then pyuic5 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560673/issues-building-pyqt5-for-python3-4-in-ubuntu-14-04-caused-by-qprinter-h-not-fou)
- http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprinter.html

The code snippet of concern from - qprinter.sip , is as seen below ---

```
%If (Qt_5_0_0 -)
%If (PyQt_Printer)

class QPrinter : QPagedPaintDevice
{
%TypeHeaderCode
#include <qprinter.h>  ### Its stated here include qprinter.h
%End
```

A hack that i thought of - which may not work though , get a Copy of the `qprinter.h` from PyQt5 and place it within the sip/QtGui DIR for PyQt4 .
How to find the Dynamic Link between `qprinter.sip` and `qprinter.h` , which would have been used while compilation.

But i cant seem to find `qprinter.h` anywhere in sip/QtGui or any other DIR within the PyQt4 Directories. ...
Kindly help / suggest way fwd - thanks

Comment: Thanks to @IanTurton from gis.stackexchange.com ---- Solved - now installing QGIS3 -- https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: Missed the line -- 
[5] 3.0 and above only available with ubuntugis (plain xenial lacks GDAL2)   , earlier had 2.14.11 , now again ended up installing 2.18.16 ..... seems need 3.0 with UbuntuGIS as plain ol vanilla Xenial lacks GDAL2 ....Whoopp...  Not my day - duped again .